# Poisson Distribution with history (puzzle)

Tags: probability

If I play several "rounds" where in each round I can add or remove balls to/from a jar, what is the probablity to remove exactly one ball and what is the average number of balls which are removed under the condition that there are balls to remove.

Further conditions are:

- A ball is allowed to stay in the jar only for a maximum lifetime of $L$ rounds
- When the lifetime of one ball has expired all balls are removed
- Otherwise balls are only added but not removed (we only remove balls if we have to)
- The average number of balls $\lambda$ added per round is known. It is less than one and the same for each round.

I was tempted to say, that the probability of removing exactly one ball is the probability that a single ball was added L rounds ago and no additional balls were added ever since. Both can be computed from the Poisson distribution.

However, that single ball might have been removed right away, because L rounds ago there was already a ball in the jar, whose lifetime had exipired.

The problem has some practical importance in scheduling algorithms, where it is highly undesirable to start a job for a single "ball".

Answer (score 0):

Your thoughts are correct. In addition to the condition you quote, you need no balls to have been added between $L+1$ and $2L$ rounds ago to avoid taking out the one from $L$ rounds ago prematurely.

Comment: This is not the full truth, because those balls between $L+1$ and $2L$ rounds ago may not have survived until $L$ rounds ago. They may have been removed due to an even earlier ball. There is something recursive going on here.